# Large external 2.5" HDD with USB Type C connector?

Tags: usb, hard-disk, usb-c

Does it really exists as for now? I want 3Tb or 4Tb of external storage.

I am searching particularly for a capacious HDD able to store my files and I want it to have fast interface onboard, at least USB3.0 Gen 1 or USB3.1.

So far I wasn't able to find it anywhere neither in my region nor globally: the only one I found was [Transcend ESD250C](https://www.transcend-info.com/Products/No-987) which is only 960Gb, couple of Seagate models not more than 1Tb, and a suspicious [Lacie brand](https://www.lacie.com/gb/en/products/rugged/), which doesn't seems trustworthy.

Is there any well-known vendors which produce the stuff or it hasn't been developed yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply buy an external Hard drive case plus a hard drive of your choice.

For a 3.5" drive, I've found this two options:

- Unykach UK 35303
- i-Tec MySafe

Then, you can attach any 3TB, 4TB or 6TB 3.5" drive you wish.

In case wou want to use a standard USB 3.1 enclosure, you can easily find USB 3.1 to USB C cables.

A lower capacity solution but faster, and much lighter is to buy a M.2 USB C enclosure (UGREEN, Sabrent, Orico, etc.) plus a M.2 SSD drive (Corsair, Western Digital, Crucial, etc.), like a 4TB Corsair @ 580€, a 2TB WD, Crucial or Corsair, all of them at around 280€). The advantage of this solution is that you have a really light-weight external drive.

Another alternative would be to have a USB RAID enclosure for 2.5" drives:
LogiLink ua0285 USB 3.0

Finally, another solution but probably a one you are not interested in (not very portable) is to have a Detached USB Storage (DAS) Raid solution for 3.5" drives like:

- QNAP TR-002
- QNAP TR-004
- TerraMaster D2-310
- TERRAMASTER D5-300C
- Fantec QB-35US3R
- ORICO 9558RU3

Comment: in case of hard drive case won't the speed degrade comparing to the native 3.1 drives? I want 2.5 only not to bother about external power. what concerns M2 enclosures I prefer HDD to keep my budget requirement low, I don't need high speeds because I will be using it as a backup solution

Comment: Speed depends on the controller. A ready-made solution can use the very same controller as a standard off-the-shelf box. You can check opinions on internet, but you can be certain that speed can drop 25% with respect to an internal connection.

Comment: thx, I will look into it

Comment: the cases you suggested claim they can handle 3.5" drives via USB-C, but on their photos I see they have ports for external power. The question: do USB-C power only is enough for 3.5" drive?

Comment: USB-C should have enough power to connect a single 3.5 drive. But based on my own experience working & designing in hardware-based USB devices, having a USB-C connector does not mean that the device is USB-C compliant or neither certified. You need to be sure about this, otherwise you might have current issues. Supplying an external unit with different hard drives is a different story, this is why they have external power; power requirements could be high enough for several drives + internal controller (in fact is a small linux computer)

Comment: got it, thx. Indeed, it is a risk to rely on that these cases have a good USB-C implementation, i'd rather not to waste money

Comment: Well, for sure, it's riskier to use a cheap brand, but I would say that the risk is higher in the PC/computer. I've seen so many computer claiming to be USB compliant and auto-disconnecting due to a high current consumption (still within the standard specs)